# Select rows based on equal values in different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I select rows based on value overlap in two different dataframes with pandas?

Say that I have two dataframes:

`df_A`:

```
latitude    measurement
-8.4        30     
-8.3        40
-8.2        50
```

`df_B`:

```
latitude    measurement
-8.4        40     
-8.2        65
-8.1        53
-8.0        100
```

I would like to compare measurements taken at the same latitude and create a dataframe that looks like this:

```
latitude    measurement_A  measurement_B
-8.4        30             40    
-8.2        50             65
```

I have tried combining the two dataframes into one `df_AB` like so:

```
latitude_A    measurement_A   latitude_B   measurement_B
-8.4          30              -8.4         40
-8.3          40              -8.2         65
-8.2          50              -8.1         53
NA            NA              -8.0         100
```

and then using `df.loc`:

```
df_AB.loc[df_AB['latitude_A'] == df_AB['latitude_B']]
```

however this results in:

```
latitude     measurement_A   measurement_B
-8.4           30              40
```

In otherwords, latitude -8.2 is skipped because they are in different rows. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
df_A.merge(df_B, how='inner', on='latitude')
```

Comment: Many thanks that works perfectly! While I have your attention how do I include multiple conditions? E.g. latitude and longitude?

Comment: Just add a list df_A.merge(df_B, how='inner', on='[latitude', 'longitude'])

Answer (score 1):

A simple table merge will do:

```
pd.merge(df_A, df_B, on='latitude', how='inner', suffixes=('_A', '_B'))
```